# how to get a questions from lex bot in lambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I tried for retrieving the questions which are asked by the lex bot into the lambda functions and to store in dynamoDB I want the syntax to get the questions from amazon lex. I tried this

"const question1=intentRequest.currentIntent.prompts.FlowerType"

but it gives me an error so guys try to help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the question that bot asked then you will not get it in JSON. The only thing you will get is Slot and slot value. Please see the input json with slots where you will get only slot value not the question asked by Lex bot

```js
{
  "messageVersion": "1.0",
  "invocationSource": "FulfillmentCodeHook",
  "userId": "897877979",
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "requestAttributes": null,
  "bot": {
    "name": "Reasturant",
    "alias": "$LATEST",
    "version": "$LATEST"
  },
  "outputDialogMode": "Text",
  "currentIntent": {
    "name": "Intent",
    "slots": {
      "SlotType": "SlotValue"
    },
    "slotDetails": {
      "Location": {
        "resolutions": [],
        "originalValue": "SlotValue"
      }
    },
    "confirmationStatus": "None"
  },
  "inputTranscript": "Your question goes here"
}
```

If you are looking for the question user asked then it is possible. The JSON getting from Lex to Lambda looks like below,

```js
{
  "messageVersion": "1.0",
  "invocationSource": "FulfillmentCodeHook",
  "userId": "876669698689967676",
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "requestAttributes": null,
  "bot": {
    "name": "LexBotName",
    "alias": "$LATEST",
    "version": "$LATEST"
  },
  "outputDialogMode": "Text",
  "currentIntent": {
    "name": "WorkingHours",
    "slots": {},
    "slotDetails": {},
    "confirmationStatus": "None"
  },
  "inputTranscript": "The question you have asked"
}
```

The key "**inputTranscript**" is where you will get the question. so you get the question by,

```
var question = event.inputTranscript
```

where 'event' is the first parameter of Lambda handler function.

Comment: The OP is asking for the question "asked **by** the lex bot". So the prompt used for eliciting a slot, not the user's input. I don't know if that's possible, if you know, maybe you can update this answer? @Vijayanath

Comment: @JayA.Little thanks for correcting me. You are correct it is not possible to get the question asked by lex bot. Only thing we will get is the Slot and Slot value.

Comment: Thanks vijayanath vishwanathan

Answer (score 0):

The response which you provide from your Lambda code through Fulfillment (`ElicitSlot`, `ElicitIntent`, `Close` etc) are the questions asked by the bot.

If you are trying to save the conversation in dynamoDB then you can make a function which will get **User Message** and **Bot Response** and save it to dynamoDB table. You can call this function just before your bot replies to the user.
That's how I did it.

**Pseudo Code:**

```
def dynamo_put_convo(user_message, bot_response):
    #your code to put items into dynamodb


def perform_action(intent_request):
    user_message = intent_request['inputTranscript']
    if source == 'DialogCodeHook':
        # your code
        validation_result = some validation code
        if validation_result == False:
            bot_response = elicit_slot_message
            dynamo_put_convo(user_message, bot_response)
            return elicit_slot()
        return delegate()

    if source == 'FulfillmentCodeHook':
        # your code
        bot_response = output_from_your_code_which_you_want_to_display_to_user
        dynamo_put_convo(user_message, bot_response)
        return close(bot_response)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    intent_name = intent_request['currentIntent']['name']
    if intent_name == 'ABC':
        return perform_action(intent_request)
    raise Exception('Intent with name ' + intent_name + ' not supported')
```

> The idea is to make a function to put records in the DynamoDB table,
>   and call that method just before your bot is sending any message to
>   the user.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I cannot understand you, please write the code in lambda functions for  getting questions asked by lex to store in dynamodb

Comment: @FedricLawrence updated the psedo code. could you tell me what exactly you did not understand? if you understand the concept then you can write the code on your own.